# Python Django user model extension

Tags: python, django

I want to add phone number feild to user model and I would like to verify email and phone when we add user to the list. I would like to know your comments on it.

1. Make a userapi which will integrate with Google or Facebook for authentication
2. this will also verify phone number using third party.

Is my approach correct? If you can provide code snippets on model, apiview it will very useful.

Thanks 
Kay

Comment: https://www.intenct.nl/projects/django-allauth/

Comment: read [this](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html) and [this](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/10/24/how-to-add-social-login-to-django.html)

Comment: This is useful information. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the existing user model to include any fields you like and authenticate on any fields.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/
Django also has support for social auth here's a guide:
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/10/24/how-to-add-social-login-to-django.html.

Your question is vague if you could be more specific, we could add more useful information.